# How do you evaluate an open source project host?

Tags: open-source, project-hosting

I am going to create my first open source project and I am trying to decide where to host it google code or codeplex.  It seems to me codeplex has a better set of community features  and google code has real svn and a version diff tool.  What has been a deciding factor for where to host your project?

Comment: don't forget the "mother" of all opensource hosts: www.sourceforge.net

Comment: Have you also consider SourceForge? It's another big hoster of opensource project that give you many tools.

Comment: +1 for google code. I never had any problems with it. It's fast and has plenty of features to help a team.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me the number one feature is getting my code in and out of the repositories, which is super easy with google code, and even assembla (altho I'm not up to date with what the latest terms of usage with assembla are). Codeplex leans towards TFS which is hard to use, but you can make it work with SVNBridge and tortoise, which is easier.

Once you worked out getting code in and out, it really comes down to personal preference.

Do you want a Wiki? 
Do you want an issue tracker?
Do you want to have automated builds?
Do you need integration with third party tools (like fogbugz or trac)?

Answer (score 1):

For [Task Coach](http://www.taskcoach.org), I started with [Sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net) and [Yahoo groups](http://groups.yahoo.com/) for mailinglists. When we added translations for Task Coach, we also started using [Launchpad](http://launchpad.net) because of its support for editing translations via the web. I considered moving Task Coach to Launchpad completely (I like Bazaar) but Launchpad does not offer website hosting, while Sourceforge does. Also, Sourceforge offers multiple version control systems these days, including Bazaar. At the moment, I'm considering to use [Uservoice](http://uservoice.com) to allow Task Coach users to vote for new features.

I guess these are the features I have been/are looking for in open source hosts:

1. Project website hosting
2. Support for end-user downloads
3. Source code version control
4. Bug/feature request/support request tracker
5. Support for editing translations
6. Mailinglists